# Chaining Observables to avoid multiple subscriptions

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have some trouble chaining these observables. I have `func1()` which throws exception on failure. In the `onError` I have `func2()` which does a database fetch and `func3()` which does a database save by modifying the fetched document. How can I chain this in order to avoid multiple subscriptions?

```
       Observable.fromCallable { func1() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .take(1)
            .subscribe({
                // update success view
            }, {
                Observable.fromCallable { func2() }
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .take(1)
                        .subscribe {
                            Observable.fromCallable { func3() }
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .take(1)
                                    .subscribe {}
                        }
                // update failure view
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

For continuing after an error, you can use the [`onErrorResumeNext()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#onErrorResumeNext-io.reactivex.Single-) operator family.
For continuing after a success, you can use the [`flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) operator family.